# How can I add a stacked growth column to my time series data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a table like below, using this dummy data:

```
data = [['Jane', 10,10.5,11,13,45,41,66,21,88,99,77,84,66,8,77,22,11,44,69,85,36,4,
         87,74,56,88,23,6,9,8,55,12,4,58,36,44,89,81,7,98,52,11,45,87,96,32,58,76],
        ['John',11,22,55,23,6,9,8,41,12,4,58,66,99,36,44,89,81,7,98,52,33,11,45,87,
         96,32,58,55,12,4,58,13,36,52,89,81,7,98,34,44,11,25,22,44,55,88,56,47],
        ['Tom',23,32,43,12,10,10.5,11,46,45,45,46,66,21,88,99,77,8,77,22,11,44,69,8511,44,77,85,99,45,63,
        89,81,7,98,3,52,89,81,7,98,13,58,36,44,89,81,7,98,52]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name','January-19','February-19','March-19','April-19','May-19','June-19',
                                   'July-19','August-19', 'September-19', 'October-19','November-19', 'December-19',
                                   'January-20','February-20','March-20','April-20','May-20','June-20',
                                   'July-20','August-20', 'September-20', 'October-20','November-20','December-20',
                                   'January-21','February-21','March-21','April-21','May-21','June-21',
                                   'July-21','August-21', 'September-21', 'October-21','November-21',
                                   'December-21','Q1 2019',
                                   'Q2 2019', 'Q3 2019', 'Q4 2019','Q1 2020',
                                   'Q2 2020', 'Q3 2020', 'Q4 2020','Q1 2021',
                                   'Q2 2021', 'Q3 2021', 'Q4 2021'])
```

This results in the follow dataframe:
[image]

Each entry indicates a growth rate.

I need to calculate 2Y and 3Y stacked growth rates using a specific formula for each month and quarter in 2021.

Formula example:

3Y Jan 21 = ((1+Jan 2021 rate) * (1+Jan 2020 rate) * (1+Jan 2019 rate)-1

2Y Jan 21 = ((1+Jan 2021 rate) * (1+Jan 2020 rate))-1

I had initially done the following, which was to transpose the data and try to use the percentage change method in Pandas, indicating a time period of 24 months for the 2 year stacked column:

```
test1 = df.T
new_header = test1.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
test1 = test1[1:] #take the data less the header row
test1.columns = new_header #
test1 = test1.reset_index()
test1.rename(columns={'index': 'Date'}, inplace = True)
test1['Jane_2Y_Growth'] = test1['Jane'].pct_change(24)
test1.tail(15)
```

[image]

However I don't think its correct because I get a different answer when I manually do the formula.

Does anyone know how to apply this formula to all of my periods in 2021? 12 months and 4 quarters.

So, the 2Y stacked growth column for Q4 2021 for example, would use the Q4 figures from 2021 and 2020.

Thanks

Comment: and what about the values from 2019 for Jane_2Y_Growth, how are they calculated?

Comment: You are missing a commata between Dec-19' and 'January-20'. That misses up your data. Can you please correct that?

Comment: Sorry all, now fixed. We only require the 2Y and 3Y values for the time periods in 2021.

Comment: but in the screenshot I see you have Q-19 and Q-20 as well @work_python

Comment: as I understand I thought you need Growth values only for these Date `['January-21', 'February-21', 'March-21', 'April-21', 'May-21',
       'June-21', 'July-21', 'August-21', 'September-21', 'October-21',
       'November-21', 'December-21', 'Q1 2021', 'Q2 2021', 'Q3 2021',
       'Q4 2021']`

Comment: Yes that’s correct

Comment: would a looping solution work for you?

Comment: If it does the job I don’t see why not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the formula example you have given :

```
3Y Jan 21 = ((1+Jan 2021 rate) * (1+Jan 2020 rate) * (1+Jan 2019 rate)-1
2Y Jan 21 = ((1+Jan 2021 rate) * (1+Jan 2020 rate))-1
```

##### Transposing and filtering values of interest from dataframe

```
NDF = df.T
NDF, NDF.columns = NDF[1:] , NDF.iloc[0]
result_df = NDF.loc[[x for x in NDF.index if '21' in x ]]
```

##### Creating placeholder columns for the resultant dataframe

```
for col in NDF.columns:
    result_df[col + '_2Y Growth'] = 0
    result_df[col + '_3Y Growth'] = 0
```

The above gives us

```
result_df
Name         Jane John Tom  ...  John_3Y Growth  Tom_2Y Growth  Tom_3Y Growth
January-21     56   96  77  ...               0              0              0
February-21    88   32  85  ...               0              0              0
March-21       23   58  99  ...               0              0              0
April-21        6   55  45  ...               0              0              0
May-21          9   12  63  ...               0              0              0
June-21         8    4  89  ...               0              0              0
July-21        55   58  81  ...               0              0              0
August-21      12   13   7  ...               0              0              0
September-21    4   36  98  ...               0              0              0
October-21     58   52   3  ...               0              0              0
November-21    36   89  52  ...               0              0              0
December-21    44   81  89  ...               0              0              0
Q1 2021        96   55  81  ...               0              0              0
Q2 2021        32   88   7  ...               0              0              0
Q3 2021        58   56  98  ...               0              0              0
Q4 2021        76   47  52  ...               0              0              0
```

Applying the formula :

```
for idx in NDF.index:
    if('21' in idx):
        idx20 = idx[:-2] + '20'
        idx19 = idx[:-2] + '19'
        for col in NDF.columns:
            result_df.loc[idx, col + '_3Y Growth'] = (1 + NDF.loc[idx, col]) * (1 + NDF.loc[idx20, col]) * (1 + NDF.loc[idx19, col]) - 1
            result_df.loc[idx, col + '_2Y Growth'] = (1 + NDF.loc[idx, col]) * (1 + NDF.loc[idx20, col]) - 1
```

##### Output :

This gives us the expected output based on the formula

|  | Jane | John | Tom | Jane_2Y Growth | Jane_3Y Growth | John_2Y Growth | John_3Y Growth | Tom_2Y Growth | Tom_3Y Growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January-21 | 56 | 96 | 77 | 3818 | 42008 | 9699 | 116399 | 1715 | 41183 |
| February-21 | 88 | 32 | 85 | 800 | 9210.5 | 1220 | 28082 | 7653 | 252581 |
| March-21 | 23 | 58 | 99 | 1871 | 22463 | 2654 | 148679 | 9999 | 439999 |
| April-21 | 6 | 55 | 45 | 160 | 2253 | 5039 | 120959 | 3587 | 46643 |
| May-21 | 9 | 12 | 63 | 119 | 5519 | 1065 | 7461 | 575 | 6335 |
| June-21 | 8 | 4 | 89 | 404 | 17009 | 39 | 399 | 7019 | 80729 |
| July-21 | 55 | 58 | 81 | 3919 | 262639 | 5840 | 52568 | 1885 | 22631 |
| August-21 | 12 | 13 | 7 | 1117 | 24595 | 741 | 31163 | 95 | 4511 |
| September-21 | 4 | 36 | 98 | 184 | 16464 | 1257 | 16353 | 4454 | 204929 |
| October-21 | 58 | 52 | 3 | 294 | 29499 | 635 | 3179 | 279 | 12879 |
| November-21 | 36 | 89 | 52 | 3255 | 253967 | 4139 | 244259 | 451135 | 21203391 |
| December-21 | 44 | 81 | 89 | 3374 | 286874 | 7215 | 483471 | 4049 | 271349 |
| Q1 2021 | 96 | 55 | 81 | 5140 | 462689 | 671 | 5375 | 4837 | 396715 |
| Q2 2021 | 32 | 88 | 7 | 395 | 32471 | 2313 | 229085 | 295 | 2367 |
| Q3 2021 | 58 | 56 | 98 | 2713 | 21711 | 1310 | 45884 | 4454 | 441044 |
| Q4 2021 | 76 | 47 | 52 | 6775 | 670823 | 2159 | 97199 | 4769 | 66779 |

**EDIT :**  As OP asked,

> Is there a way to add the new columns to the bottom instead and
> instead of labelling them 'Jane_2Y Growth' for example, label then
> 'January-21 2Y growth'. This way they are added to the index and do
> not have any names in them, just the date and the growth period.

Instead of adding the result to `results` dataframe we can add it to `NDF` datafrmae in the appropriate cell. The result would be stored in `NDF`

```
for idx in NDF.index:
    if('21' in idx):
        idx20 = idx[:-2] + '20'
        idx19 = idx[:-2] + '19'
        for col in NDF.columns:
            NDF.loc[idx + ' 3Y Growth', col] = (1 + NDF.loc[idx, col]) * (1 + NDF.loc[idx20, col]) * (1 + NDF.loc[idx19, col]) - 1
            NDF.loc[idx + ' 2Y Growth', col] = (1 + NDF.loc[idx, col]) * (1 + NDF.loc[idx20, col]) - 1
```

This gives us the expected output :

|  | Jane | John | Tom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January-19 | 10 | 11 | 23 |
| February-19 | 10.5 | 22 | 32 |
| March-19 | 11 | 55 | 43 |
| April-19 | 13 | 23 | 12 |
| May-19 | 45 | 6 | 10 |
| June-19 | 41 | 9 | 10.5 |
| July-19 | 66 | 8 | 11 |
| August-19 | 21 | 41 | 46 |
| September-19 | 88 | 12 | 45 |
| October-19 | 99 | 4 | 45 |
| November-19 | 77 | 58 | 46 |
| December-19 | 84 | 66 | 66 |
| January-20 | 66 | 99 | 21 |
| February-20 | 8 | 36 | 88 |
| March-20 | 77 | 44 | 99 |
| April-20 | 22 | 89 | 77 |
| May-20 | 11 | 81 | 8 |
| June-20 | 44 | 7 | 77 |
| July-20 | 69 | 98 | 22 |
| August-20 | 85 | 52 | 11 |
| September-20 | 36 | 33 | 44 |
| October-20 | 4 | 11 | 69 |
| November-20 | 87 | 45 | 8511 |
| December-20 | 74 | 87 | 44 |
| January-21 | 56 | 96 | 77 |
| February-21 | 88 | 32 | 85 |
| March-21 | 23 | 58 | 99 |
| April-21 | 6 | 55 | 45 |
| May-21 | 9 | 12 | 63 |
| June-21 | 8 | 4 | 89 |
| July-21 | 55 | 58 | 81 |
| August-21 | 12 | 13 | 7 |
| September-21 | 4 | 36 | 98 |
| October-21 | 58 | 52 | 3 |
| November-21 | 36 | 89 | 52 |
| December-21 | 44 | 81 | 89 |
| Q1 2019 | 89 | 7 | 81 |
| Q2 2019 | 81 | 98 | 7 |
| Q3 2019 | 7 | 34 | 98 |
| Q4 2019 | 98 | 44 | 13 |
| Q1 2020 | 52 | 11 | 58 |
| Q2 2020 | 11 | 25 | 36 |
| Q3 2020 | 45 | 22 | 44 |
| Q4 2020 | 87 | 44 | 89 |
| Q1 2021 | 96 | 55 | 81 |
| Q2 2021 | 32 | 88 | 7 |
| Q3 2021 | 58 | 56 | 98 |
| Q4 2021 | 76 | 47 | 52 |
| January-21 3Y Growth | 42008 | 116399 | 41183 |
| January-21 2Y Growth | 3818 | 9699 | 1715 |
| February-21 3Y Growth | 9210.5 | 28082 | 252581 |
| February-21 2Y Growth | 800 | 1220 | 7653 |
| March-21 3Y Growth | 22463 | 148679 | 439999 |
| March-21 2Y Growth | 1871 | 2654 | 9999 |
| April-21 3Y Growth | 2253 | 120959 | 46643 |
| April-21 2Y Growth | 160 | 5039 | 3587 |
| May-21 3Y Growth | 5519 | 7461 | 6335 |
| May-21 2Y Growth | 119 | 1065 | 575 |
| June-21 3Y Growth | 17009 | 399 | 80729 |
| June-21 2Y Growth | 404 | 39 | 7019 |
| July-21 3Y Growth | 262639 | 52568 | 22631 |
| July-21 2Y Growth | 3919 | 5840 | 1885 |
| August-21 3Y Growth | 24595 | 31163 | 4511 |
| August-21 2Y Growth | 1117 | 741 | 95 |
| September-21 3Y Growth | 16464 | 16353 | 204929 |
| September-21 2Y Growth | 184 | 1257 | 4454 |
| October-21 3Y Growth | 29499 | 3179 | 12879 |
| October-21 2Y Growth | 294 | 635 | 279 |
| November-21 3Y Growth | 253967 | 244259 | 2.12034e+07 |
| November-21 2Y Growth | 3255 | 4139 | 451135 |
| December-21 3Y Growth | 286874 | 483471 | 271349 |
| December-21 2Y Growth | 3374 | 7215 | 4049 |
| Q1 2021 3Y Growth | 462689 | 5375 | 396715 |
| Q1 2021 2Y Growth | 5140 | 671 | 4837 |
| Q2 2021 3Y Growth | 32471 | 229085 | 2367 |
| Q2 2021 2Y Growth | 395 | 2313 | 295 |
| Q3 2021 3Y Growth | 21711 | 45884 | 441044 |
| Q3 2021 2Y Growth | 2713 | 1310 | 4454 |
| Q4 2021 3Y Growth | 670823 | 97199 | 66779 |
| Q4 2021 2Y Growth | 6775 | 2159 | 4769 |

Comment: I actually have a question. Is there a way to add the new columns to the bottom instead and instead of labelling them 'Jane_2Y Growth' for example, label then 'January-21 2Y growth'. This way they are added to the index and do not have any names in them, just the date and the growth period.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you, what do we mean by `add the new columns to the bottom instead `

Comment: So at the moment, the final output has a series of new columns. Instead of adding the new data as columns, can they be added as rows instead? So example row name would be 'January-21 2Y growth' and it would go beneath the row 'Q4 2021'.

Comment: So you want to add it as a row in your main dataframe?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I worded that poorly!